# Drupal running behind a proxy send emails with links to the wrong domain/IP

Tags: 7

So I have a public site http://www.mysite.com with the following vhost entry:

```
ProxyPass /press http://123.45.67.89/press
ProxyPassReverse /press http://123.45.67.89/press
```

And I have a Drupal site running at `http://123.45.67.89/press` ready to receive requests.

All works fine except emails sent from the Drupal site come through as:

```
http://123.45.67.89/press/user/reset/1/1384468691/3WY1S7QUJK8Wdp78U9Itu2ygw-KenVLY_9mgBZeTOy8
```

Which is not accessible to the general public, and instead needs to output:

```
http://www.mysite.com/press/user/reset/1/1384468691/3WY1S7QUJK8Wdp78U9Itu2ygw-KenVLY_9mgBZeTOy8
```

How can I trick Drupal to think it's being accessed on the desired domain? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, forgot all about setting `$base_url` in `settings.php`. By default it is commented out, but I've now set it to:

```
$base_url = 'http://www.mysite.com/press';
```

Comment: I am the author, I don't really need clarification. In any case I'll try and elaborate.